# Ubuntu refuses to boot due to an error - (EE) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Read error 19.

Tags: 14.04, boot, gnome, touchpad, synaptics

Here are some details of what led to this issue. 
I had recently added the Gnome shell to my Ubuntu 14.04 and then upgraded to Gnome 3.12 following the instructions on this website - [Latest install of Gnome on ubuntu](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-gnome-3-12-ubuntu-14-04/)
On installing, I found out that it has a few bugs and wanted to revert back to the older version of Gnome. So I followed the instructions on the same website to install a purge tool to remove Gnome 3. And then on rebooting, I encountered this error. Is there any way to fix this error? Or is the only option I have is to install Ubuntu all over again which would result in me losing my data?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could follow [this](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=122385) that has the same issue as yours, but I suggest for simplicity, just reinstall Ubuntu, as this will get rid of all headaches that you would get trying to fix the problem. I learnt the hard way when I upgraded to GNOME 3.12.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried following the guidelines present in the website suggested but it didn't help me much. I guess its better to just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @SupreethVK, it is much better to reinstall Ubuntu, at least you won't run into problems. If you liked my answer and it worked for you, please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) it. :)